# Designer Support? System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon

Tags: wpf, ribbon, system.windows.controls.ribbon

I am wanting to implement a Ribbon Control on a new WPF application using the .NET 4.5 Framework, and have come across the System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon class. Is there no designer support from VS2013 for using the ribbon controls from the ToolBox. Or am I missing something ?

Here is the MSDN documentation for it. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbon%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: As the docs page you linked to says, the Ribbon is a host class for different types of controls, eg the RibbonTab class, see eg [WPF Ribbon Tab view in Designer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362854/wpf-ribbon-tab-view-in-designer) for how to use that in the designer

Comment: I don't follow. Is there a package I am probably missing ?

Comment: @stuartd that's not what's being asked. I have the same question and I got here. only 15 views lol... does nobody use ribbons?

Comment: Not a lot of knowledge out here yet?

Comment: @Zuoanqh Oct 2019 and only 66 views, so I guess not!